# Symfony messenger listen for even sent to failure transport/queue

Tags: symfony, symfony-messenger

short background, in application we using `doctrine` transport for failed queues, so if message failed (all retries failed) messenger storing it to failed messages table and it's waiting for further actions. And I need somehow listen when message is sent to that table and update prometheus gauge and send alert.

I tried to do it in a same way I sending other messenger related metrics (with event subscriber, I found it much flexible than middlewares), so basically by listen to one of the `https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#messenger-events`, but I found it's not possible to catch a moment when messenger sending it to failure transport, messenger has `SendMessageToTransportsEvent` but it does not provide a transport name, so I can't understand if it's a failed or not...

Also I found messener has `SentToFailureTransportStamp` stamp, but for some reason that stamp is not present in the envlope when message failed and will be send to failed queue, but depends on class description `Stamp applied when a message is sent to the failure transport.` it should...

Only idea I have is to make a collector which will query failed messages table periodically and send amount of records to prometheus, but what if I'll change transport to something else???? It's mean I'll need to change a collector all the time...

Is there a way to catch a moment when messenger sending message to failed queue??? Thank you in advice!!!

Comment: Have the same problem, have you already solved it?

Answer (score 0):

We cant get last retry before go to failed queue that way:

```
final readonly class FailedEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            WorkerMessageFailedEvent::class => 'onWorkerMessageFailedEvent',
        ];
    }

    public function onWorkerMessageFailedEvent(WorkerMessageFailedEvent $event): void
    {
        $message = $event->getEnvelope()->getMessage();
        if (!$message instanceof SomeMessage) {
            return;
        }

        if ($event->willRetry()) {
            return;
        }

       // here we have last retry before go to failed 


    }

}
```